# Автоматическое исполнение кода в указаную дату

Tags: php, javascript

Хочу сделать на сайте возможность публикации рекламы от пользователей, естесственно пользователь может выбрать дату начала публикации, хочу чтоб вы подсказали как на php или может при помощи js сделать автоматическую публикацию этой рекламы в указанную дату?!

Comment: Cron для unix. Планировщик для windows. Можно ещё извратиться и написать демон на php

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь таблицу, в ней хранишь рекламу и дату публикации. Пишешь скрипт, который проверяет неопубликованную рекламу которая по времени должна быть опубликована. Изменяешь статус рекламы. Скрипт ставишь на исполнение по крону каждый день в 24:00.

Comment: Подскажите еще как это  делать, как написать код, ибо я с такими вопросами никогда не встречался

Comment: По-моему я очень детально описал что нужно сделать. Код за вас бесплатно я писать не буду. Попробуйте начать и приходите с конкретными вопросами.

Comment: То что я нашел в интернете мне подходит на сто процентов, это "0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/логин/public_html/myscript.php". Вопрос теперь в какой файл это нужно вставлять (.txt, .php) в какое место сервера и как он запускается или как запустить???

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужны кроны.

Что есть кроны - у вас есть некий урл, например в вашем случае example.com/queue-ads/, который выполняет проверку/запись на очередь рекламы ваших юзеров (ничего особенного, просто точно такая же запись, как вы бы и делали без отсрочки).
Т.е. если мы заходим на example.com/queue-ads/, то ваш скрипт срабатывает и пишет все, что нужно. Можно сделать, например, раз в день или раз в час запрос.
Итого - кроны, это просто запрос на урл с некой периодичностью.

https://cron-job.org/en/ - я пользуюсь этим, бесплатный (платный контент вроде тоже есть, но у меня до сих пор работает бесплатно).

Либо же, если у вас ispManager, то там должны быть тоже кроны, если провайдер хостинга позволяет.

При желании вы можете и свои запросы написать на вызов этого урла, но тогда ваш скрипт должен работать постоянно.

Comment: То что я нашел в интернете мне подходит на сто процентов, это "0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/логин/public_html/myscript.php". Вопрос теперь в какой файл это нужно вставлять (.txt, .php) в какое место сервера и как он запускается или как запустить???